# Adding column values in dataframe with common characters in title

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `R dataFrame` with multiple columns.
I intend to do some data cleansing by adding some columns together based on the presence of some common characters in the title.

simple example

```
df

date               go_pax       full_pax       plus_pax
2019-03-11           7            23             14
2019-03-12           11            5              6
2019-03-13           20            4              37
```

expected output: add all columns with the characters `pax` in a new column "bookings"

```
df_demand

date                bookings
2019-03-11           44
2019-03-12           22
2019-03-13           61
```

I am not using the simple

```
 df_demand <- data.frame("date" = df$date, "bookings" = df$gO_pax +  df$full_pax + df$pLUS_pax)
```

because the columns with `pax` will be different for different input data.

I tried something like this

```
df_demand <- data.frame("date" = df$date, "bookings" = df$grep("pax", names(df)))
```

I haven't found a working syntax yet.

Edit:

```
I need to put a logic such that I am adding columns with the characters pax
```

I will not use numbers to specify columns. The overall data I have has over 20 columns.

Final edit

Based on all the nice answers, this is what worked for me

```
pax <- grep("pax", names(df))
df_demand <- data.frame("date" = df$date, "bookings" = rowSums(df[pax]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the `rowSums` of the the columns other than the first and create a `data.frame` with the first column of the original dataset

```
data.frame(df1[1], bookings = rowSums(df1[-1]))
#         date bookings
#1 2019-03-11       44
#2 2019-03-12       22
#3 2019-03-13       61
```

---

If we need to specify the columns that have 'pax'

```
nm1 <- grep("pax", names(df1))
data.frame(df1[1], bookings = rowSums(df1[nm1]))
```

---

Or another `base R` option is `Reduce` with `+`

```
data.frame(df1[1], bookings = Reduce(`+`, df1[nm1]))
```

---

If we need a `tidyverse`, option (no need to reshape again), `selecg` the columns that have 'pax' as substring of column names, then use `+` within `reduce` to create the 'bookings'

```
library(tidvyerse)
df1 %>% 
   transmute(date, bookings = select(., matches("pax")) %>% 
                 reduce(`+`))
#        date bookings
#1 2019-03-11       44
#2 2019-03-12       22
#3 2019-03-13       61
```

---

Or another option is `rowSums` which we first posted here

```
df1 %>%
   transmute(date, bookings = rowSums(.[nm1]))
#        date bookings
#1 2019-03-11       44
#2 2019-03-12       22
#3 2019-03-13       61
```

Here, we don't need any reshaping and it should be fast

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(date = c("2019-03-11", "2019-03-12", "2019-03-13"
 ), go_pax = c(7L, 11L, 20L), full_pax = c(23L, 5L, 4L), plus_pax = c(14L, 
 6L, 37L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 2):

With `tidyverse` you can try:

```
df %>%
 select(date, contains("_pax")) %>%
 gather(var, val, -date) %>%
 group_by(date) %>%
 summarise(bookings = sum(val))

    date       bookings
  <chr>         <int>
1 2019-03-11       44
2 2019-03-12       22
3 2019-03-13       61
```

Or with just `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
 select(date, contains("_pax")) %>%
 transmute(date = date,
           bookings = rowSums(.[2:length(.)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sapply`

```
df = data.frame(df[,1],
                "bookings" = sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) sum(df[x, grep('pax', colnames(df))])))
```

Comment: I think a better option if you are doing `sum` would be `apply(df[grep('pax', names(df))], 1, sum)`

Comment: Yes, that would be better.